# Audio out of sync in premiere pro and my audio is have constant framerate. Anybody know how to fix it?

Tags: audio, adobe

[This is the details of the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoJuL.png)

when i play my gameplay in vlc media player it plays fine and the audio syncs with the video but when i import the video into premiere pro the audio gets out of sync. i don't know why is this happening. i researched about it and tried converting my video into CFR using Handbrake software but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that maybe you don't have a setting selecting one your timeline that keeps the audio and video tracks synced. I personally like my timeline settings [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMdPL.png)

Let me know if that works, if not maybe try adding a screen recording of the issue or some screenshots?